# Find index of Max value in array inside kernel

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, kernel, opencl, reduction

I'm very new to OpenCL and I'm creating 2 functions for finding index of minimum OR maximum value in kernel function. According to this [article](http://developer.amd.com/resources/articles-whitepapers/opencl-optimization-case-study-simple-reductions/)  I was able to find index of the minimum value based on parallel tree reduction.

How can I change it to find only index of maximum value in array? This is my working Min function:

```
__kernel void Min(__global float* buffer, __global int* result, __const int length, __local float* scratch, __local int* sc_index)
{

    int global_index = get_global_id(0);
    int local_index = get_local_id(0);

    // Load data into local memory
    if (global_index < length) {
        scratch[local_index] = buffer[global_index];
        sc_index[local_index] = global_index;
    } else {
        // INFINITY is the identity element for the min operation
        scratch[local_index] = INFINITY;
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);    
    for(int offset = get_local_size(0) / 2;  offset > 0; offset >>= 1)
    {
        if (local_index < offset) {
            float other = scratch[local_index + offset];
            int other_index = sc_index[local_index + offset];

            float mine = scratch[local_index];
            int mine_index = sc_index[local_index];

            if (mine < other) {
                scratch[local_index] = mine;
                sc_index[local_index] = mine_index;
            }
            else {
                scratch[local_index] = other;
                sc_index[local_index] = other_index;
            }
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    if (local_index == 0) {
        result[get_group_id(0)] = sc_index[0];
    }
}
```

I guess I should change INFINITY to -INFINITY for finding index of max value.

Also what is the exact meaning of the double angle brackets here?

```
for(int offset = get_local_size(0) / 2;  offset > 0; offset >>= 1) {
```

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: `offset >>= 1` means shift offset by 1 to the right and assign to offset it is shorthand for `offset = offset >> 1`